# How to Same jQuery call for different ID's objects?

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic

I have a number of text-boxes which are created dynamically:

```
<?php
    $columns = $_POST['n_cols'];
    for ($i=0; $i<$columns; $i++) {
        ?>
        <input type='text' id="autocol_<?php echo $i; ?>" name="autocol_<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Then I have a jQuery call to make these text-boxes behave as an auto-complete field:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    jQuery(function($) {
        jQuery('#autocol_').autocomplete({'showAnim':'fold','select':function(event, ui) {
        },'source':'/myproject/index.php?r=Controller/autocomplete&table=newtable'});
    });
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Is there a way in jQuery to use the above function to handle the autocomplete field for all the text-boxes **that were dynamically created and have different ids**? Something like jQuery will take all the text-boxes whose id start with **'autocol'** and then manage the auto-complete function for all of them?

Thanks

Comment: This is more than possible, your going to have to build your own solution per say to make it work. Remember your not limited to just id's. You can use class's to define multiple elements in with one block of functionality then break the functionality down by the ID or another class given. Cause your also not limited to one class per class on an element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is such selector:

```
jQuery('input[id^=autocol_]').autocomplete...
```

Answer (score 2):

on your situation, 
do

```
$("[id^='autocol_']")
```

or

```
$("input[id^='autocol_']")
```

but you can put `class` attribute to group your elements for later purpose
like:

```
<input type='text' class='autocol_input' id="autocol_<?php echo $i; ?>"
```

and later you can select with `class` instead of `id`
like:

```
$(".autocol_input').autocomplete....
```

Comment: I'll also try using class. Thanks!